# Hide Hibernate's SQL output for a single package

Tags: hibernate

Using `Hibernate` and `Spring Boot`, recent versions, I log the SQL and parameters like this:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Though, I also have a scheduled job that runs every second and it has to execute a query. This pollutes the logs a lot.

Is there a way to disable Hibernate logging for a single package?